# How geolocated app take places list?

Tags: iphone, geolocation

does anyone knows how applications like Foursquare, Gowalla, Brightkite, take the list of the nearby places?

Answer (score 0):

[Geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org/) has some very good [databases of places worldwide](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/readme.txt) (e.g., all cities with a population > 1000).

Comment: Yes but it's not what I search. I want to know, possibly, what Foursquare and similar services uses.